# Top / Bottom Windows position on Full Screen

Tags: unity, firefox, java, screen

I have a problem while running Firefox on Full Screen Mode only. (While on Maximize and Half screen work as expected)

I have Firefox Full Screen and I would like to have a Java Window or around 1/4 screen size always on Top of the Firefox Full Screen Window.
 - I have already selected Always on Top for Java Window

But Java windows remains going to the back (Bottom) of Firefox Window on Full Screen (F11)

Is there any way to select Firefox to be always on back (Bottom?)